# dojo - remove ComboButton styling and hover action

Tags: dojo, styling, dijit.form

I'm creating a dijit.form.ComboButton programmatically. However, I'd like to remove all the dijit styling from it (eg. the dijitButtonNode class). I also want to disable the style from changing when I hover over it.

Currently, I'm just doing this after I create the ComboButton:

```
dojo.query(".dijitButtonNode", myComboButton.domNode).removeClass("dijitButtonNode");
```

So my two questions are, 1) is this the best way to remove the styling, and 2) how do I disable the hover styling?

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
<div id="menu" dojoType="dijit.myComboButton">
    <span>Save Me</span>
    <div  dojoType="dijit.Menu" id="cmbmnu">
        <div dojoType="dijit.MenuItem">
            Save as
        </div>
        <div dojoType="dijit.MenuItem">
            Save as Email Draft             
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

JS:

```
   dojo.provide("dijit.myComboButton");
   dojo.declare('dijit.myComboButton', [dijit.form.ComboButton],{
   postCreate:function(){
    this.inherited(arguments);
    //console.log(this.containerNode);
},
startup:function(){

    var x =dijit.byId('cmbmnu');

}
   })
```

Inside the postCreate method do your Dom manipulations  (css class removals).
Inside the startup method do your Dom manipulations (css class removals) for the menu or the toolbar that you might have nested inside the combobutton.

Note myComboButton is a custom widget